# Custom error page in nuxt 3 application not working

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

In my pet project with Nuxt 3 v# 3.6.0 I can't set up custom error page.

In project, I have layouts (with default.vue) and pages (with index.vue) folders.
Wherever I put the error.vue file, the system won't recognize it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#rendering-an-error-page) of Nuxt 3, the custom error page is supposed to be a file named `error.vue` in the root directory that receives an error object property, alogside `app.vue` page.

Maybe the problem of your project is that the `app.vue` page is missing.

The code of a simple error page could be:

- error.vue

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  error: Object,
  required: true,
});

const handleError = () => clearError({ redirect: '/' });
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ error.statusCode }}</div>
  <div><button @click="handleError">Go to the home page</button></div>
</template>
```

See a working [replication](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-v1u27c?file=error.vue&initialpath=foo) using `nuxt@3.6.0`.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Nuxt and thought that the only way to get advantage of nuxt way of routing is putting all pages into page folder and get rid of `root\app.vue` ... :(((

Comment: Check my replication link. You can use the `app.vue` page and use the routing with pages inside the `pages` folder. If it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: After I've add app.vue ,<MyNav> and remove wrong error.vue files - everything is working!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I was following old tutorials. Damn! Thanks again.